# Wordpress: Slug adds suffix

Tags: php, wordpress, slug

How do I prevent wordpress from adding number suffix to my URL.

I am trying to have the below two urls, but when I created the Arabic version the number 2 was appended to the first one. Below is what I want

```
http://site-name/en/seven-days

http://site-name/ar/seven-days
```

But this is what I get.

```
http://site-name/en/seven-days-2


http://site-name/ar/seven-days
```

I understand that this was added to wp

The pages need to have the same slug at least, even if the title should be different.

Comment: @charankumar I did, it would just go back and update the other one

Comment: This should not be a problem, if you have your different language versions set up as individual “sites” within a WP multi-site. If you didn’t do that, but are just trying to “fake” a multi-language site in some other ways, it is rather to be expected that you run into problems like this.

Comment: @CBroe That makes sense

Answer (score 1):

The WP engine wants unique post names and will always append a number to achieve that. You'll need to use a custom permalinks plugin to get what you want. Here's an example of someone with the same issue, working around it with a permalink plugin: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/polylang-share-same-slug-between-languages/